# Is there a way to Insert a Random Number into a already existing Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, random, sql-insert

I have the Homework to set up a Table for a Kicker Tournament. I have to write an INSERT statement where i will Fill the Goals for Player 1 and Player 2 with random numbers.
So thats more or less clear. I got it like that :

```
DECLARE @MAX_VALUE INT = 10, @MIN_VALUE INT = 0, @RANDOM_NUMBER INT;
SELECT @Random_Number = FLOOR((@Max_Value - @Min_Value + 1)
* RAND() + @Min_Value)

DECLARE @RANDOM_NUMBER2 INT;
SELECT @Random_Number2 = FLOOR((@Max_Value - @Min_Value + 1)
* RAND() + @Min_Value)


INSERT INTO dbo.SpielTabelle
VALUES(4,1,3,@RANDOM_NUMBER,@RANDOM_NUMBER2)
```

Now the problem is if one Person has 10 (thats why max value 10) the person has won and i dont want that the second number is also 10. How can i include an if clause into this?

This is for SQL Server 2017, i tried to include an if clause but it didnt work. Always syntax fault.

```
DECLARE @MAX_VALUE INT = 10, @MIN_VALUE INT = 0, @RANDOM_NUMBER INT;
SELECT @Random_Number = FLOOR((@Max_Value - @Min_Value + 1)
* RAND() + @Min_Value)

DECLARE @RANDOM_NUMBER2 INT;
SELECT @Random_Number2 = FLOOR((@Max_Value - @Min_Value + 1)
* RAND() + @Min_Value)


INSERT INTO dbo.SpielTabelle
VALUES(4,1,3,@RANDOM_NUMBER,@RANDOM_NUMBER2)
```

I expect that when its final i can just put in the new Game ID and then it automatically will fill everything else in and every game has 1 person that has 10 goals and 1 that got less.

Comment: *"Always syntax fault"*; and what is that "fault"?

Comment: SQL, the language, doesn't use IF clauses, nor are they needed. It works with *sets*, not loops.  Explain what you actually want to do, not how you expect to do it. Do you want 10 non-repeating numbers from 1 to 10? Or is it only 10 that shouldn't be repeated? 1-10 in a random order is essentially 1-10 shuffled

Comment: Hello Lukas, could you include the desired result in a table?

Comment: Hello, i want 2 numbers. The first one should be random generated (0-10) so that means that player one did score X (Random number 0-10) goals. Then it should check if the random Number X is 10, if yes generate another random number from 0-9 (Because 10 is the max Goal count). If the number is not 10 i want that the statement enters a 10 into the goal count for Player 2. Is that at least a bit understandable? English is not my first language and i try to explain it the best way possible for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could put in a little WHILE loop to test for both values being 10 and calculate new values until they are both not 10:

```
DECLARE @MAX_VALUE INT = 10, @MIN_VALUE INT = 0, @RANDOM_NUMBER INT;
SELECT @Random_Number = FLOOR((@Max_Value - @Min_Value + 1)
* RAND() + @Min_Value)

DECLARE @RANDOM_NUMBER2 INT;
SELECT @Random_Number2 = FLOOR((@Max_Value - @Min_Value + 1)
* RAND() + @Min_Value)

WHILE @RANDOM_NUMBER=10 and @RANDOM_NUMBER2=10
BEGIN
SET @Random_Number = FLOOR((@Max_Value - @Min_Value + 1)
* RAND() + @Min_Value)

SET @Random_Number2 = FLOOR((@Max_Value - @Min_Value + 1)
* RAND() + @Min_Value)
END

select 4,1,3,@RANDOM_NUMBER,@RANDOM_NUMBER2
```